# What is the unit of the "signal" when running nmcli?

Tags: networking, network-manager, nmcli

What is the unit of the signal returned when I run `nmcli dev wifi list`? The confusing part is that the signal result is different when I run `iwlist wlan0 scan`

nmcli output:

```
SSID                              BSSID               MODE             FREQ       RATE       SIGNAL   SECURITY   ACTIVE  
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'CantDoSteam'                     C0:::::7D   Infrastructure   5180 MHz   54 MB/s    72       WPA WPA2
```

and `iwlist scan` result:

```
Cell 02 - Address: C0:56:27:BA:3B:7F
                    Channel:36
                    Frequency:5.18 GHz (Channel 36)
                    Quality=44/70  Signal level=-66 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"CantDoSteam"
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s
                              36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
```

Can someone help me understand what signal in nmcli means and what Quality and Signal level are? Which of these two is the most accurate?

Answer (score 5):

It looks like the `SIGNAL` value is a percentage. Maximum signal is 100.
The more is the better.

`iwlist` gives output in dBm. It is always negative. The more is the better too. "-20" is better that "-50".

I tested it with a powerful router close to the client machine. It shows 100.